# Screenshot not embedding into RobotFramework log file when used with SikuliX

Tags: robotframework, sikuli

I am unable to have my screenshot automatically embed itself into the RobotFramework log file after my test is run.  I am using:

- SikuliX 1.1.4
- RobotFramework 3.0.4 JAR distribution (placed in C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\Extensions

I am able to run my simple test and also have a report/log kicked out - along with a screenshot.  The only trouble is that the screenshot is not visible in the log file when viewed in a browser (tried Chrome and FF).

This is my code as written in Sikuli:

```
runScript("""
robot

*** Settings ***
Library   Screenshot

*** Test Cases ***
Try to take a screenshot
   Take Screenshot   mypic   80%

""")
```

My folder where the logs are outputted looks like this after the test is run:

```
./log.html
./mypic_1.jpg
./output.xml
./report.html
./test2.robot
```

So far, all I have come across when searching the net is that the embed should 'just happen automatically' when using the 'Take Screenshot' keyword.

I have not tried this scenario with RobotFramework by itself - I think that may be my next step, but hoped someone would have an easy solution since I am wanting to use these two packages together.  I am wanting to leverage Sikuli to help with my GUI intensive tests and RF for its' reporting and screenshotting capability.

Comment: When you look at the log.html source, do you see this element in it, just where the screenshot image is supposed to be? `<a href="path_to/mypic_1.jpg"><img src="path_to/mypic_1.jpg" width="80%">`

Comment: I do, here is the like as it appears in the log.html:

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
window.output["strings"] = window.output["strings"].concat(["*","*Test2","*C:\\Users\\[user]\\Desktop\\test2.sikuli.robot\\test2.robot","*test2.robot","*Try to take a screenshot","*Take Screenshot","*Screenshot","*<p>Takes a screenshot in JPEG format and embeds it into the log file.\x3c/p>","*mypic, 80%","*<a href=\"mypic_1.jpg\"><img src=\"mypic_1.jpg\" width=\"80%\">\x3c/a>"]);
</script>

Comment: Interesting, the link is there in the source, and you showed a dir listing where the file is also present. What is shown when you view the log file in a browser - is the picture substituted with a placeholder of a missing file; do you mind showing the html around, as the browser renders it? The one in your previous comment is a js function that combines all texts, let's see the final DOM.

Comment: I think this link will work.  The actual HTML code is a bunch of script tags all within the Body tags.  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y3HdacNeqt-x8w8bdQnw1dLQ_hcqQo9g/view?usp=sharing

Comment: After some testing - this MAY be a bug with Sikuli itself.  I ran this same script with a normal installation of RF as well as with the same JAR distribution of RF that I am using with Sikuli from the commandline.      In both cases, the log file has my screenshot embedded.  I was running the script from within the Sikuli IDE before.  Currently waiting on confirmation from the Sikuli crew, but my bug write up is here -> https://bugs.launchpad.net/sikuli/+bug/1793035

Comment: Interesting find, glad you're getting to the bottom of it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the comment made by temp temp didn't solve my issue right away, it did put me on the right track.  After copying over the pip installed version of RF as mentioned in the comment, I removed the RF JAR file from my Extensions folder (not even sure why I tried this).  Once I removed the JAR file, the image started embedding itself in the log.  So it seems the combination of the RF version included with Sikuli combined with the RF JAR file was causing my issue.

Comment: Update - this turned out to be an issue with Sikuli itself.  It has been fixed in build 1.1.4 (2018-09-19_07:17.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a similar problem with Sikurix 1.1.4 (with RF 3.0.0)
When overwriting the Robot directory of Robot Framework 3.0.4 in "C:\Users\xxxx\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\Lib\robot", images are now embedded in Log.html.

[image]

Comment: When you say you overwrote the Robot directory, what do you mean exactly?  What did you overwrite it with?

Comment: The expression "overwriting" was incorrect. I'm sorry.    
  
First , I deleted  
 "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\Lib\robot"  
  
Next, I copied  
"I:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\robot" (pip install robotframework)   
to "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sikulix\Lib\" .    
  
Thank you for your comment.

Comment: I tried this, but the screenshot still did not embed into the log file.